# Elements from an array list, Copy each other while Sorting

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, arraylist, filereader

I'm trying to sort my Arraylist from greatest to least with data taken from a .txt file. Although it works, the last two elements seem to copy each other. Any idea why this happens and how to fix it?

My code:

```
class totalCompare implements Comparator<Status>{
 @Override
public int compare (Status o0, Status o4)
        {
            return o4.total-o0.total;
        }
}
vStatus.sort(new totalCompare());
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\filepath"));
                System.out.println("Pri.G \t 1st Dose \t FUll Vax \t Booster \t Total");
                for (Status status: vStatus)
                {
                    writer.write(status.category);
                    writer.write(" "+ status.onedose);
                    writer.write(" "+ status.fdose);
                    writer.write(" "+ status.booster);
                    writer.write(" "+ status.total);
                    writer.newLine();
                    System.out.println(status.category +" \t\t"+ status.onedose +" \t\t"+ status.fdose +" \t\t"+ status.booster+" \t\t"+ status.total);
                }
                reader.close();
                writer.close();
```

Original List:
`A1 25826 24698 11155 60278 A2 32812 31801 14839 73887`

Expected Output:
`A2 32812 31801 14839 73887 A1 25826 24698 11155 60278`

Actual Output:
`A2 32812 31801 14839 14839 A1 25826 24698 11155 11155`

Comment: I can't see how this could be possible with the code you've shown. I ran something similar (although instead of outputting to a file, I just added a `toString` method to the `Status` class and did `System.out.println(status);` and everything looks as it should. Are you sure there isn't any other relevant code that could be affecting your results?

Comment: Most likely there's a typo in populating the fields of `Status` instances.

Comment: Thanks! Both comments helped me resolve the problem ! Have a good day !

Comment: @LiiLucs if you could post your solution as an answer to your question, that would help question askers in the future!